# How use a Future[] in Spark streaming transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

With Spark streaming, what is the best solution to call a Web services or other long services without consume a task ?

Is it possible to use a Future[] in a map(), filter(), etc ?

Comment: not sure what you mean with 'without consume a task'. Could you explain?

Comment: If I have 4 core, and each invoke a long web services, the spark streaming process must wait all the long web services before start a new micro batch. I'm right ?

Comment: does you web service call depend on the data received via the stream?

Comment: Yes. I would like to call a web services with a value from the DStream, to generate another DStream.